# How can I clear the JavaScript console in the Safari 6 developer tools?

Tags: safari, development, macos

In previous versions of Safari the JavaScript console in the Developer Tools (aka Web Inspector) had a little 'clear' button at the bottom that emptied out console items, which was useful for getting rid of clutter between debug sessions.

As of Safari 6, the new Dev Tools don't seem to have such a button. Manually using `clear()` and `console.clear()` doesn't work either. The 'Clear Console' item in the contextual menu doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Short of `console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")`, is there a way to clear the console in Safari 6?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use Command-K (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) to clear Safari 6 Web Inspector console.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks so much, this has been driving me nuts. Undocumented shortcuts FTW :P

Comment: The command-K thing was working for me for a little while, then it stopped. Seems like Safari 6 is pretty inconsistent.

Comment: It looks like the shortcut only works when the console (not the prompt) has focus. Although it doesn't seem documented, it's at least consistent with Terminal.app. :)

Comment: you really saved my nerves ;)

Comment: undocumented, where as `clear()` is [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW31) and doesn't work!

Comment: Point up for you! ;) But it is a bug that Apple should really solve...

Answer (score 0):

## As of May 2019:

---

Even though, current Safari version is far beyond `6` (it is `12`, actually). A shortcut that works for me in FireFox 67.0, Safari 11.1.2, Chromium 76.0.3802.0 is:

 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

---

P.S.: posting just in case somebody will come here looking for "*cross-browser*" solution (like I did).